# Angular practice with Tour of Heroes and Error in AppRoutingModule

Tags: angular

I practicing with Angular [Tour of Heroes](https://angular.tw/tutorial#tour-of-heroes-app-and-tutorial). Everything is fine until [app-routing.module](https://angular.tw/tutorial/toh-pt5#add-the-approutingmodule) part. I got error after I following instruction add and edit app-routing.module.ts. Even I copy and paste all codes from [final code review](https://angular.tw/tutorial/toh-pt5#final-code-review)
still get the same error.

```
Error: ./node_modules/@angular/router/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/router.js 43:12
Module parse failed: Identifier 'ɵngcc0' has already been declared (43:12)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.js
 * ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| import * as ɵngcc0 from '@angular/core';
| import * as ɵngcc1 from '@angular/common';
> import * as ɵngcc0 from '@angular/core';
| import * as ɵngcc1 from '@angular/common';
| class RouterEvent {
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "angular-tour-of-heroes",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "~11.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "~11.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^11.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "~11.2.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1102.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~11.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.1.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you try to remove your `node_modules` directory and try `npm install` ?

Comment: or just `npm ci`

Comment: thank you all for the suggestions and my problem solved

Answer (score 1):

I have a workaround, It's not the proper solution but it works for me.
**Solution is to open file node_modules@angular\router_*ivy_ngcc*_\fesm2015\router.js**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VU6N5.png)

```
import * as ɵngcc0 from '@angular/core';
import * as ɵngcc1 from '@angular/common';
// import * as ɵngcc0 from '@angular/core';
// import * as ɵngcc1 from '@angular/common';
```

comment above two lines that are repeated. for me, it's lines 43 and 44.
And restart your Angular Application. It will work!

Comment: Worked for me, thx. Seems to be a bug - two sets of identical import lines.

Answer (score 0):

This problem´s so common in Angular. To resolve you should delete the folder "node_modules" and download this folder again just use this command "npm install" in the path of your application.

OR

You should import a `RouteModule` like this:

```
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class YourModule { }
```

terModule like this: